# Make Spyder Variables have Colour

Tags: python, variables, spyder

so I am coding with spyder and I want to make variables have color.

I am not sure if spyder even support variable coloring because I wasn't able to find anything here:
[image]

Very thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This feature is not available in Spyder's editor at the moment, sorry.